# How to allow manual input into a cell being changed by another cell

Tags: vba, database

So, first, I have mostly been learning VBA by the seat of my pants over the past year-ish and googling things when trying to figure out what I need to do. And even then what I know is limited I think. I don't think I have quite figured out how to find the answer to my current roadblock which I had a hard time figuring out how to word the title to communicate what it is that I am trying to do.

With that said, when it comes to going through any answer y'all might have for me to try, I apologize if I ask a lot of clarifying questions to ensure I am understanding. So thank you for bearing with me in those instances.

This paragraph is just a little background on the worksheet if you may find it helpful, otherwise just skip to the next paragraph. The worksheet I am working in mainly has all index- match formulas that use tables in some hidden worksheets. The formulas are set within the worksheet cells, which works fine, but I want the option to edit those cells that currently I have locked to prevent those formulas from accidently getting deleted. I do have different save locations of the file just in case of course. I do have some checkboxes hiding and unhiding cells and/or worksheets and a Userform where I can enter some data into, have it do a couple calculations, and then place that onto the worksheets that they need to go to. The checkboxes and Userform stuff is most of my VBA knowledge at this time.

What I want is one cell to return a value based on what is in another cell as well as to clear what is in that cell if you clear the value that is in that original cell, which I have achieved.
I am planning to have this be for multiple different Cell Combinations (just between 2 different cells mostly) with differing criteria. Since formatting is generally the same among them all, I will just include one of those instances below to keep things focused for me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range) 

    Application.EnableEvents = False 
    Dim GDS As Range 
    Dim GDSInterp As Range 

    Set GDS = Sheet21.Range("D230") 
    Set GDSInterp = Sheet21.Range("E230") 
    If GDS.Value >= 0 Then 
        Call GDSInterpretation 
    ElseIf GDS.ClearContents Then 
        GDSInterp.ClearContents 
    End If 
    Application.EnableEvents = True 

End Sub
```

The sub that is called within the above code for context is below (I initially wrote this without doing Dim And Set though I should've to make it less bulky, but haven't changed it yet because I want to address my question first incase I need jump to a different way of doing things)

```
Sub GDSInterpretation() 

    If Sheet21.Range("D230").Value = "" Then 
        Sheet21.Range("E230") = "" 
    ElseIf Sheet21.Range("D230").Value >= 0 And Sheet21.Range("D230").Value < 10 Then 
        Sheet21.Range("E230") = "Normal" 
    ElseIf Sheet21.Range("D230").Value >= 10 And Sheet21.Range("D230").Value < 20 Then 
        Sheet21.Range("E230") = "Mild" 
    ElseIf Sheet21.Range("D230").Value >= 20 And Sheet21.Range("D230").Value < 31 Then 
        Sheet21.Range("E230") = "Severe" 
    ElseIf Sheet21.Range("D230").Value > 30 Then 
        Sheet21.Range("E230") = "Check Raw" 
    End If 

End Sub
```

So, with the worksheet change I can enter a value in D230 and get the correct value in E230 as well as use delete or backspace to clear D230 and then have E230 clear. For some reason (and I am sure someone might be able to explain it to me to allow me to maybe think about how to write things differently) when I did not have the Clear Contents portion in the Worksheet_Change function, the first part of Sub GDSInterpretation would not happen (If Sheet21.Range("D230").Value = "" Then Sheet21.Range("E230") = "") when clearing D230 with Backspace or Delete and I would have to manually clear the whatever was in E230.

So for here forward just think D230 as "Raw Score" and E230 as "Standard Score"

Now the part that I haven't figured out. Sometimes, with what this data is used for, we will not have the data that goes into Raw Score but may have the data that goes into Standard Score. Because that is usually in the instance of comparing 2 data sets, I want us to be able to enter the Standard Score into the location it is supposed to go so we can compare the 2 sets. However, with the above as I know some will be able to tell, I can't do that and it doesn't occur.
With how the formula currently stands, if I try typing anything into Standard Score what occurs is that the equations check to see if there is anything in Raw Score and then update Standard Score accordingly because it's a Worksheet change. That's the only way I know how to achieve what I have achieved at this time and haven't figured out how to allow me to enter data into Standard Score and keep a lot of the automated populating and clearing of data.

If I remove the ClearContents portion in the Worksheet Change and remove the first statement of GDSInterpretation where it checks if Raw Score is empty and returns empty in Standard Score, I can manually change the value in Standard Score and have what I entered stay. However, then there is always a value shown in Standard Score, which I do not want, even if I backspace or delete what I entered into Standard Score.
If I remove just the ClearContents portion, I still cannot enter a value into Standard Score and keep it, but I have to manually Backspace or Delete Standard Score if I Backspace or Delete Raw Score.

So, how would I go about still having the conditions to achieve what I currently have (correctly returning a value in Standard Score based of a value in Raw Score and clearing Standard Score when I Backspace or Delete Raw Score) while allowing me to enter a value into Standard Score while Raw Score is blank and not have my worksheet change Standard Score or set up in a way where I have a value that always shows in Standard Score?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when using the Change event you want to restrict when it runs: you don't want your calculations to run every time any cell on the sheet is changed, only when specific cells get updated.

So you can do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const RNG_GDSINT As String = "D230,D232" 'only check cells in this range
    
    'call GDS interpretation passing in any cells changed in RNG_GDSINT
    GDSInterpretation Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(RNG_GDSINT))
    
End Sub

Sub GDSInterpretation(rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range, v, cRes As Range, msg
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'nothing to process
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells 'loop over each changed cell
        Debug.Print c.Address
        msg = ""
        v = c.Value
        Select Case True
            Case Len(v) = 0: msg = ""
            Case v > 0 And v < 10: msg = "Normal"
            Case v >= 10 And v < 20: msg = "Mild"
            Case v >= 20 And v < 31: msg = "Severe"
            Case v > 30: msg = "Check raw"  '###this doesn't mesh with the previous case...
        End Select
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = msg
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. Works like a charm.
Clarifying cause I have mostly been poking into VBA with little bits here and there.

Dim c As Range, v, cRes As Range, msg

Is this statement a constant for any other similarly constructed sub like the one it is in? Or like all the other Dim statements they can be whatever you choose?

I guess I haven't seen Dim like that so I just want to make sure I know what's happening there really.

Comment: You can always use a comma separated list of declarations like that. Adding a type for each item is optional but you should use specific types where you can.

Comment: Alright, thank you for all of this! It was very helpful